# "Debug" function in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging, google-chrome-devtools

probably a silly question, but somehow i ended up on the `debug` function available in Google Chrome Console, which if i try to print it on the console i get:

```
ƒ debug(function, condition) { [Command Line API] }
```

however i'm totally unable to `console.log` something from it in any way, and I can't find any documentation online...
I've tested it on Firefox and i get `Uncaught ReferenceError: debug is not defined` so it's not cross platform, but maybe for development purpose it might be helpful

Maybe is related to `debugger;`?...

Comment: Yes, it appears to set a breakpoint in an arbitrary function (like `debugger;`). I've just tried `function x() { return 1 }; x(); debug(x); x();` in the console

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/breakpoints#function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is documented in the [Console Utilities API Reference](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/utilities):

> #### `debug(function)`
>
> When the specified function is called, the debugger is
> invoked and breaks inside the function on the Sources panel allowing
> to step through the code and debug it.
>
> ```
> debug(getData);
> ```
>
> Use `undebug(fn)` to stop breaking on the function, or use the UI to
> disable all breakpoints.
>
> For more information on breakpoints, see [Pause Your Code With
> Breakpoints](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/breakpoints).